Poor text rendering on an OLED monitor
I am new to modern Macs. I connected my PG49WCD OLED monitor to a M4 Mac mini via HDMI. I think the monitor has an unusual subpixel layout. All text is rendered in a very distracting way that looks oversharpened with a strange color halo appearance. I tried playing with font smoothing adjuster and different resolutions, but I didn't find a satisfying solution. The same monitor has good text rendering with Linux and Windows (using different machines). Is there anything I'm missing?
I'm attaching a picture, but it's hard to see, you can see the shimmery halo around that dark icon though.


I did some more reading and found out that this is "on purpose" by apple. There are some workarounds, but none of them work for me or are up to date. I intend to install linux as soon as it's available. for M4 but I was hoping to be able to use this thing until then, but as it is it's giving me headaches.

MacOS tends to look bad on displays that are lower than 100 ppi. However, your display is 49 inches wide, 5120 x 1440, giving you 109 pixels per inch.
That ought to give you a 'reasonable' image: there are plenty of 4K 27" displays with the same pixel density, and they look ok on macOS; though not as good as with a high-density display.
It's possible that some special characteristic of the display is a factor. Apple no longer uses sub-pixel rendering, as they had to licence it from Microsoft. All their displays (laptops, iMacs, etc) have much higher resolutions.

They had to license it? Do you have a source for that, all I found was forum posts? How do all other operating systems have it then?

@AndreasHartmann "All other"? Linux uses a different type rendering system.
